# Do Yajurveda 40.9, Yajurveda 32.3 and Bhagavadgita 7.20 reject idol worship?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, mantras, bhagavata-purana, yajur-veda, idols

First of all, I am a Hindu myself and I am saying this with no intentions of converting to any other religion but there some misconceptions that really boggle my mind.

The biggest of them is that in the Vedas, the Upanishads and even in the Bhagavad Gita it is prevented to worship idols and it is said that God is formless and He has no picture. The following verses are some examples:

> “They enter darkness those who worship natural things.They sink deeper
>   in darkness those who worship sambhuti (created things)" (Yajurved
>   40:9)
>
> "God Supreme or Supreme Spirit has no ‘Pratima’ (idol) or material
>   shape" (Yajurved chapter 32 verse 3)
>
> “Those whose intelligence has been stolen by material desires they
>   worship demigods i.e. idols." (Bhagavad Gita 7:20)

And the most opposing being:

> "The ignorant believe that un-manifest Para Brahma (One God)
>   incarnates or takes manifestations, because they do not completely
>   understand My highest, immutable, incomparable, and transcendental
>   existence." (Bhagavad Gita 7:24)

I feel like this clearly says that God does not incarnate into avatars but we believe in Lord Rama, Lord Krishna... etc.

Hindus worship idols, make pictures of God, the concept of avatars of God is supported in Hinduism. And also... in the Shrimad Bhagavata Purana it is mentioned in the following verse the acceptable materials to make an idol:

> śailī dāru-mayī lauhī lepyā lekhyā ca saikatī mano-mayī maṇi-mayī
>   pratimāṣṭa-vidhā smṛtā [SB - 11.27.12]
>
> Meaning: The Deity form of the Lord is said to appear in eight
>   varieties — stone, wood, metal, earth, paint, sand, the mind or
>   jewels.

The question is, doesn't it feel like the Vedas and the Bhagavata Purana are opposing each other?

If we look at Islam, the concept of God in it is completely clear and free of doubt that that there is no God but Allah and Muslims should not worship anything other than Allah. Nowhere in Islam two things are pointing against each other.

Again, I have absolutely no intentions of converting to Islam or any other religion. And also, in no way am I saying that Hinduism is a false religion because if it was false... it wouldn't have been alive right now. It would've been long gone in the time of Emperor Aurangzeb when he cut the head of the great [Guru Teghbahadur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guru_Tegh_Bahadur) of Sikhism. It is a miracle that Hinduism is being sustained without any terrific or convulsive movements where people are forced to accept Hinduism despite being one of the oldest religions and having suffered so many attacks, but still alive haven't executed any violent attacks forcing any one into the religion as done before in Islam and Christianity. Though, it should be noted that these kind of movements are prohibited in Islam and Christianity. I personally have also experienced small miracles and have been told of unbelievable miracles witnessed by my parents that have no doubt in my mind that Hinduism is not a false religion.

Nevertheless, these  are still some of the facts about Hinduism that boggle me and I would like to know if any of you have a true answer to this question.

Briefly, I would like to know:

1: Doesn't it look like the Vedas and the Bhagavata Purana are opposing each other? Why do different Hindu scriptures look like they're opposing each other?

2: Will we never know the true meaning of "God is formless, as well as with form" written in the Vedas in this life?

3: In Bhagavad Gita 7:24 it states:

> "The ignorant believe that un-manifest Para Brahma (One God)
>   incarnates or takes manifestations, because they do not completely
>   understand My highest, immutable, incomparable, and transcendental
>   existence."

Doesn't this clearly state that God has no avatars? But we still believe in divine incarnations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Krishna consider/believe the devotee who worship him as saguna superior than who worship as nirguna?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11520/why-does-krishna-consider-believe-the-devotee-who-worship-him-as-saguna-superior)

Comment: The problem  is that in hinduism the scriptures are many and varied and all of them at many times contradict with each other..So,one can't get the "whole" idea by reading just one of those many scriptures.. And even if one studies all of them chances are that still he will remain confused..The scriptures are not that easy to decipher at all..

Comment: "Hinduism is extremely confusing for me" is **not** a good title. A big turn off for many to even read your question fully. I suggest you break it up into multiple individual Q-s. Also see **[How do I ask a good question?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)** Your confusion can be broken down into multiple, individual, logical Q-s. And if you break them down enough, you'll find answers to most of your doubts on this site already exist!!!

Comment: I think that one of the reasons why you are confused is that you have provided poorly translated verses. Find some better translations and it will be more clear to you. And there are many verses in the Vedas that tell that God has a form in which he appears in this world, and that we should serve and worship that God.

Comment: The translations you quoted are mostly used by Islam preachers to attract Hindus who don't know much about scriptures into their religion. I have seen many doing thatTo know the proper meaning of Bhagavad Gita, read authentic commentaries of  scholars like Ramanuja, Adi Shankara, Madhwa etc.,

Comment: Please be specific on one topic and don't ask multiple questions in one post. Consider to visit [How do I ask good question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I can see what you are saying.

Comment: @SreeCharan That may very well be true.

Comment: @Pandya I have updated the question as an attempt to better express myself. See if there's anything else that I need to correct.

Comment: @UdayKrishna I completely believe in these texts and am in no way saying that they are wrong. I'm just seeking the truth because I'm a little confused.

Comment: @sv. I have reformatted the question so people can easily understand me. Please check if there's anything else that I need to change.

Comment: @PardeepKumar OK, your question is reopened. You can express yourself at "about me" of your profile. Express your question well here. Your Q/A post**s** will automatically express your self.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49828/discussion-on-question-by-pardeep-kumar-hinduism-is-extremely-confusing-for-me).

Comment: Puranas(smrti) are not authentic, if any contradiction between vedas(Sruti) and puran(Smrti), then vedas will be considered.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Don't believe blindly what you see on internet. Hinduism or सनातन धर्म (*Sanātana Dharma*) can't be false as name itself says it is eternal and has "Dharma" in it. Hinduism is confusing for some people because they don't read scriptures in Sanskrit or in other language with proper interpretations of Guru or Acharyas.

To understand Hinduism properly, first you should have some knowledge about Sanskrit Language or Veda Bhasha. Sanskrit is language of Attributes. It doesn't have proper nouns.  Krishna is named for person who is "black". Shiva is named for a person who is "auspicious". But a person has many attributes. You can call a person by any of his attributes. But Lord or Parabrahma has infinite attributes. So, Parabrahma has infinte names. Unlike other languages, a Sanskrit name  gives some info or qualities a person possess. So, if you come across a name "Shiva" in scripture, you should understand that person has an attribute "auspiciousness" besides other additional attributes.

Sanskrit has fixed [Dhatus](http://wiki.yoga-vidya.de/Sanskrit_Verbal_Roots_List_with_English_Translation) (Verb roots), by which you can analyze the meaning of word by yourself without help of any dictionary. You can even guess Sanskrit word for modern English words. For example, we can derive Sanskrit words for upload and download. Quoting from [blog by Gurudev](http://www.hitxp.com/articles/sanskrit-lessons/sanskrit-lesson-1-secret-science-sacred-sanskrit/):

> Edit: Since many readers asked about giving a practical example of
>   creating new words in Sanskrit by giving one for Download, have
>   updated the article with one for download and upload. T**he attribute of
>   descending or fetching is Avataara in Sanskrit, so one word for
>   Download in Sanskrit could be Avataarayati or the act of fetching.
>   Avaroha represents the attribute of going down, so Download can also
>   be Avarohayati**
>
> **Similarly for Upload we can call it Urdhvayati where Urdhva is an
>   attribute representing upwards in Sanskrit. Aaroha also represents the
>   attribute of ascent or going up and hence Upload can also be called
>   Aarohayati**
>
> Not only these, you can create any number of words for upload and
>   download in Sanskrit using the attributes representing upward or
>   ascent, and downward, fetching or descent. For instance consider the
>   terms Unnati and Avanati, which represent progress and downfall
>   respectively. Take the Sanskrit attribute which can represent File,
>   Patrika. So File uploading and File downloading could be Patrikonnati
>   and Patrikavanati respectively! **The options are limitless!**

My intention is not to boast Sanskrit language, but to affirm that Sanskrit language is eternal and so the language of Vedas (Veda Bhasha). Sanskrit has no need to evolve in vocabulary like other languages, though there may be changes in grammar.

Many people have common attributes. An attribute can refer to multiple persons. Meaning of words in a Sanskrit sentence depends on context. Some foreign authors who translated our scriptures failed to derive meaning based on context and rather they translated literal meaning. Quoting from the same blog:

> Take for instance the translations making round about people eating
>   beef or killing the cow during the vedic period. The whole basis of
>   this myth is translations of Sanskrit verses like the one which
>   actually means “control your sense organs” which was translated as
>   “kill the cow“, all just because the word used was **go/gau can refer
>   not only to cow, but also to sense organs in Sanskrit**. So when taken
>   out of context and translated using its most popular object, you end
>   up with misinterpretations like these. **Sanskrit translation can never
>   be done by going word by word, the entire context should be used as
>   the basis to understand the meaning.** And there are multiple rules and
>   hints to understand the context of words which we shall learn in the
>   future lessons of this series

You can read  [introduction lessons to Sanskrit by Gurudev](http://www.hitxp.com/articles/sanskrit-lessons/), where author explains beautifully about Sanskrit language. Nothing can replace reading our Hindu Scriptures in Sanskrit. Root problem for misinterpretations is lack of Sanskrit Knowledge.

It is also believed Vedas are source of all languages. Refer [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15121/what-mleccha-languages-are-used-in-the-vedas-according-to-purva-mimamsa) to know more details.

Vedas are eternal scriptures and they are valid for all times. It doesn't matter which yuga you live or which epoch (Kalpa) you live or in which Loka you dwell. Vedas are infallible truths where each and everything can be verifiable. This is what Sri Swami Prabhavanada says in the book [Spiritual heritage of India](https://archive.org/details/spiritualheritag1963prab),

> **The authority of the Vedas does not depend upon anything external**.
>   They themselves are authority, being the knowledge of God. And, as we
>   shall see later, **their truth is verifiable by any spiritual aspirant
>   in transcendental consciousness**.

The Rishis who have gone into deep Tapsya heard them (in transcendental consciousness) . We may not understand them properly and verify all their contents by our limited consciousness. Thus, we need to study them under a knowledgeable Guru (preceptor).

Now coming to your question, you main question is about idol worship. No scripture explicitly rejects idol worship, including Vedas. Indeed, they are not just idols. They have *prana* in them. We invite Lord or Consciousness into them with Mantras. This process is called [Prana Pratishta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prana_Pratishtha). Those who condemn idol worship are just half baked Jivas. However, we don't need to invite Lord into Swayambhu (self manifested) murtis, such as Tirupati Venkateswara and Jyotirlingas of Shiva.

**Do Vedas and Gita reject idol worship?**

This question is already answered [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2140/3500) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/253/3500) . Quoting some verses from the above mentioned answers.

> dve vāva brahmaṇo rūpe, mūrtaṃ caivāmūrtaṃ ca [Brh. Up - 2.3.1] 
>   - God (Brahman) has two modes, formless (nirakara, asambhuta) as well as form (sakar, sambhuta).

So, Lord is both Sakara (with form) and Nirakara (without form). You can worship Lord in Sakara or mediatate on Him in Nirakara. Indeed, [Lord is everything](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15705/3500).
He is also Saguna (with attributes) and Nirguna (without attributes).

Yajurveda Sloka 40.9 you mentioned in the question refers to verse 9 of chapter 40 in *Vajasaneyi Samhita* of *Shukla Yajurveda.*  Vajasaneyi Samhita is available now only in two recensions, "Kanva" and "Madhyandina", since many recensions are lost due to various historical reasons. This chapter 40 of Vajasaneyi Samhita is also called as Isha Upanishad.

Above Sanskrit verse 40.9 is from Madhandiya recension.

> अन्धं तमः प्रविशन्ति ये ऽसम्भूतिम् उपासते 
>  ततो भूय इव ते तमो य उ
>   सम्भूत्याम् रताः
>
> andhaṁ tamaḥ praviśanti ye 'sambhūtim upāsate 
>  tato bhūya iva te
>   tamo ya u sambhūtyām ratāḥ

Kanva recension of same 40.9 is

> अन्धं तमः प्रविशन्ति ये ऽविद्याम् उपासते 
>  ततो भूय इव ते तमो य उ
>   विद्यायाम् रताः
>
> andhaṁ tamaḥ praviśanti ye 'vidyām upāsate 
>  tato bhūya iva te tamo
>   ya u vidyāyām ratāḥ

Same verse with "Sambhutim" is present in 40.12 of Kanva and same verse with "Vidyam" is present in 40.12 of Madhandiya. Only order of verses are changed in different recensions. Let us analyze these two verses.

Verse with "Vidya" is easy to understand.

> andhaṁ tamaḥ praviśanti ye 'vidyām upāsate 
>  tato bhūya iva te tamo
>   ya u vidyāyām ratāḥ
>
> They who worship Avidya alone fall into blind darkness ; and they who
>   worship Vidya alone fall into even greater darkness. (or)
>
> Into blinding darkness pass they who adhere to karma and into still
>   greater darkness, as it were, they who delight in meditation.

[Adi Shankara](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/ishavasya-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc143816.html) says

> Now follows a statement of the distinction between the respective
>   fruits of meditation and karma, as an argument for their simultaneous
>   practice. Otherwise, if of the two thus proximately stated, one only
>   is known to bear fruit and not the other, the relation between them
>   would be (according to rules of interpretation, not one of
>   co-ordination but) only that of subordination.

Refer introduction section of the [this page](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/ishavasya-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc143816.html) to know summary of first 8 verses. This verse says both Meditation and karma are important. Indeed, verses 9 to 18 give emphasis for both Karma and Upāsanā.

Now, verse 12 says

> andhaṃ tamaḥ praviśanti ye'sambhūtim upāsate |  
> tato bhūya iva te tamo
>   ya u sambhūtyāṃ ratāḥ || 12 ||
>
> Into blinding darkness pass they who are devoted to the unmanifest, and into still greater darkness, as it were, they who
>   delight in the manifest

As we know the context of verses, we can properly understand verses. Adishankara says

> Saṃbhavanam means birth. That which is born and is an effect is
>   sambhūti. asambhūti is [Page 23] what is other than sambhūti i.e.,
>   prakṛti, the undifferentiated cause whose essence is nescience and
>   which is the source of all activity and desire. They who devote
>   themselves to such Cause enter (as may be expected) darkness which is
>   correspondingly blind in its nature. Sambhūtyām i.e., in the
>   phenomenal Brahman known as Hiraṇyagarbha. They who delight only in
>   Him enter darkness which is, as it were, more blinding still.

[Griffith](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/wyv/wyvbk40.htm) also uses the words "Sambhuti" and "Asambhuti" in his translation. So, Sambhuti and Asambhuti are manifested and unmanifested and this verse says one must worship both states of Supreme Brahman.

You can also see Vaishnava interpretation of above verse [here](http://www.ramanuja.org/sv/bhakti/archives/jan98/0166.html).

The translation in your question says it is bad to "worship natural things". But on the other hand, we see divinity in everything. This divinity can be explained with simple logic as said by Swami Krishnananda in his book "[lessons on upanishads"](http://www.swami-krishnananda.org/upanishad/upan_01.html). I don't quote it here as this will make answer very lengthy.

Verse 32.3 from Vajasaneyi Samhita  of Shukla Yajurveda with translation of [Griffith](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/wyv/wyvbk32.htm)

> ná tásya pratimā́ asti yásya nā́ma mahád yáśaḥ \ 
>  hiraṇyagarbʰá
>   íty eṣáḥ \ 
>    mā́ mā him̐sīd íty eṣā́ \ 
>    yásmān ná jātá íty
>   eṣá \
>
> 3.There is no counterpart of him whose glory verily is great. In the
>    beginning rose Hiranyagarbha, etc. Let not him harm me, etc. Than whom
>    there is no other born, etc.

This verse describes  formless and unmanifested aspect. As we know, Brahman is manifested and unmanifested and at the same time He has form and He is formless.

Some people just misinterpret or give too much emphasis for certain words.

Krishna Paramatma never explicitly rejected idol worship in Bhagavad Gita. I think translations you come across were given by some Hindu haters or by haters of idol worship (to uphold their own Religion).

Lord says the following in Bhagavdgita 7.20 (translated by A Mahadeva Sastri),

> bahūnāḿ janmanām ante 
>  jñānavān māḿ prapadyate 
>  vāsudevaḥ
>   sarvam iti 
>  sa mahātmā su-durlabhaḥ
>
> 20.Those whose wisdom has been led away by this or that desire resort to other Gods (Devatas), engaged in this or that rite, constrained by
>   their own nature.

Adishankara commentary says

> Their desires for progeny, cattle, svarga and the like deprive them of
>   their power of discrimination, and they resort to **other Gods
>   (Devatas), other than Vasudeva, the Self**. They engage in rites
>   peculiar to the worship of these Gods ; they being constrained to do
>   so by their own nature (prakriti), by that peculiar tendency
>   (samskara) which they acquired in the previous births.

**1. Doesn't it look like the Vedas and the Bhagavata Purana are opposing each other? Why do different Hindu scriptures look like they're opposing each other?**

No. Vedas never explicitly support or reject idol worship but on the other hand Puranas extol idol worship. Indeed, we are worshipping Lord inside the idol not idol itself.

**2. Will we never know the true meaning of "God is formless, as well as with form" written in the Vedas in this life?**

Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 2.3.1 (translated by Swami Madhavananda) says

> ढे वाघ ब्रह्मणो रूपे-मूर्त चैवामूर्त च, मत्र्य चामृत च, स्थितं च यच्च,
>   सच्च त्यश्च ॥ १ ॥
>
> Brahman has but two forms-gross and subtle, mortal and immortal,
>   limited and unlimited, defined and undefined.

Adishankara says

> Brahman or the Supreme Self has but two forms, through the
>   superimposition of which by ignorance the formless Supreme Brahman is
>   defined or made conceivable. The word "Vava' (indeed) is emphatic.
>   Which are those two forms? The gross and subtle. The other phases of
>   the gross and subtle are included in them; so they are counted as two
>   only. What are those phases of the gross and subtle? These are being
>   mentioned: Mortal, subject to destruction, and inmortal, its opposite.
>   Limited, which goes a little distance and stops, and unlimited, which
>   goes on, is pervasive, the opposite of "limited.' Defined, having
>   particular characteristics that distinguish it from others, and
>   undefined, the opposite of that, which can only be distantly referred
>   to, as something we know not what.

Water exists as liquid at room temperature but changes its state to ice at 0 °C. Water exists as liquid, solid and Vapour (Gas). It depends on certain physical conditions. Similarly, Supreme Brahman, who is beyond dualities, is perceived differently by different people. He is the one with form and without form. He is both unmanifested and manifested.

**3. BG 7.24 clearly state that God has no avatars? But we still believe in divine incarnations.**

This is what Lord says in [7.24](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-7-24/) (translated by A Mahadeva Sastry),

> avyaktaḿ vyaktim āpannaḿ 
>  manyante mām abuddhayaḥ 
>  paraḿ
>   bhāvam ajānanto 
>  mamāvyayam anuttamam
>
> Unintelligent men, who do not know Me perfectly, think that I, the
>   Supreme Personality of Godhead, Krishna, was impersonal before and
>   have now assumed this personality. Due to their small knowledge, they
>   do not know My higher nature, which is imperishable and supreme.

Sri Adishankaracharya explains this verses as follows

> The foolish regard Me as the unmanifested coming into manifestation, knowing not My higher, immutable, unsurpassed nature.
>   Not knowing my higher nature as the Supreme Self, theignorant think
>   that I have just now come into manifestation, having been unmanifested
>   hitherto, though I am the ever luminous Lord.

Here Krishna never condemns any worship of Saguna form or idol worship. He just says that fools and ignorant people do not know his higher nature which is immutable and unsurpassed. Here Krishna says about His highest nature but this doesn't mean that Lord won't descend by donning Physical body. Lord has both manifested and unmanifested form. He says only few persons know His true form by going into transcendental consciousness. Lord says His true nature at highest level was unborn and imperishable. This is what Adishankaracharya says,

> I am not manifest to all, veiled (as I am) by Yoga-Maya. **This
>   deluded world knows not Me, unborn and imperishable**.
>
> I am not manifest to all people ; that is to say, I am manifest only
>   to a few who are my devotees. I am veiled by Yoga Maya. Yoga Maya is
>   the Maya which is none other than the Yoga or union of the three
>   gunas. Or, Yoga is the firm will of the Lord or Isvara. The Illusion
>   or veil thereby spread is called Yoga Maya. Wherefore people are
>   deluded and know Me not as unborn and imperishable. That Yoga Maya by
>   which I am veiled and on account of which people do not recognise Me,
>   is Mine, i. e, subject to My control, and, as such, it cannot obstruct
>   My knowledge— the knowledge of the Isvara, of the possessor (or
>   wielder) of the Maya, just as the glamour (maya) caused bya juggler
>   (mayavin) does not obstruct his own knowledge.

Though Sun is present all the times, we can only see it with normal eyes during day time. Even Lord can only be seen by few of His sincere devotees. Maya stops us from seeing Him and only true knowledge can break that Maya.

This doesn't talk anything about Avatara.  Lord says in [4.7](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-4-7/)

> yadā yadā hi dharmasya 
>  glānir bhavati bhārata 
>  abhyutthānam
>   adharmasya 
>  tadātmānaḿ sṛjāmy aham
>
> Whenever and wherever there is a decline in Dharma (righteousness), O
>   descendant of Bharata, and a predominant rise of Adharma —at that time
>   I descend Myself.

So, finally to know proper meaning of Hindu Scriptures either read them in Sanskrit (Veda Bhasha) or in any language with commentaries of knowledgable Acharya or learn them under a knowledgable Guru.

You can read [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13703/3500) to know how Vedas are preserved. However, some portions of Smriti got interpolated over the vast period of time. But you get essence of Hinduism by reading translations of commentaries of knowledgeable Acharyas.

Comment: You have made me understand these misconceptions further more. Thank you very much for that. Please pray for me that my faith may be strong. And I may very well have offended you a little too with my extremely unwise words. Please forgive me for that.

Comment: @Pardeep No need to get offended.Such is power of Maya. It deludes even those  sages. Ask questions and get answers.Truth is what we need. Don't stop questioning. May Lord Shiva destroy your doubts by imparting knowledge.

Comment: @Pradeep edit your question with misinterpreted verses and exact questions what you want to know. We can open it.

Comment: Thank you very much brother. I have updated the question. See if you can clarify any further. The answer I most want is the 3rd one. Which is: In Bhagavad Gita 7:24 it states: "The ignorant believe that un-manifest Para Brahma (One God) incarnates or takes manifestations, because they do not completely understand My highest, immutable, incomparable, and transcendental existence." Doesn't this clearly state that God has no avatars? But we still believe in divine incarnations. Or is this also another case of wrongly translated verses due to Sanskrit language being unique?

Comment: @PardeepKumar Sorry for delay. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help brother! This really means a lot because I had much misinterpreted knowledge of these verses given by ignorant people. But now through the correct and verified verses and explanations that you have provided me, I am clear of misunderstandings. And for that, I thank you very much brother! I really do not have words to express my gratitude! :)

Comment: Absolutely smashing answer!

Comment: @The Destroyer - great answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your question shows your confusion and not that Hinduism is a confused and corrupt religion. While I did not like the tone of your question (fake Hinduism),
I decided to answer to clear your confusion. I am posting couple of
passages about the nature of God as explained by Sri Ramakrishna.

> No one can say with finality that God is only 'this' and nothing else.
> He is formless and again He has forms. For the bhakta He assumes
> forms. But He is formless for the jnani, that is, for him who looks on
> the world as a mere dream. The bhakta feels that he is one entity and
> the world as another. Therefore God reveals Himself to him as a
> Person. But the jnani – the Vedantist, for instance - always reasons,
> applying the process of 'Not this, not this'. Through this
> discrimination he realizes, by his inner perception, that the ego and
> the universe are both illusory, like a dream. Then the jnani realizes
> Brahman in his own consciousness. He can not describe what Brahman is.
>
> Do you know what I mean? Think of Brahman, Existence-Knowledge-Bliss
> Absolute, as a shoreless ocean. Through the cooling influence as it
> were, of the bhakta's love, the water has frozen at places into blocks
> of ice. In other words, God now and then assumes various forms for His
> lovers and reveals Himself to them as a Person. But with the rising of
> the sun of knowledge, the blocks of ice melt. Then one doesn't feel
> any more that God is a Person, nor does one see God's forms. What He
> is can not be described. Who will describe Him? He who would do so
> disappears. He cannot find his 'I' anymore.

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna**

If you read through the passages you will see that God has both the formless aspect of ordinary water and the form aspect of water frozen into ice. The formless aspect can not be worshipped because the human mind is like a little bottle that can not contain the whole of the infinite sea of Brahman. The form aspects of Brahman can be worshipped because the little human mind is capable of thinking about a form. There is no confusion here. If you want to attain the formless then you have to use methods like 'Neti Neti' or try to answer questions like 'Who am I?' since it is not possible to worship It. If your interest is in God with form then you can worship the form. Worship of a form is the easier method.

**Additional Material**

I am adding this section in response to the references given in the question.
Let us look at the very first one which says:
“They enter darkness those who worship natural things.They sink deeper in darkness those who worship sambhuti (created things)" (Yajurved 40:9)

The above translation should be read with extreme caution. For example,the Arya Samaj translation of Sri Devi Chand translates the shloka differently:

> Abandoning God, deep into the shade of the blinding gloom fall the
> **worshippers of eternal unborn Matter**. They sink to darkness deeper yet
> who are engaged in the **material pleasures of the world**.

(**Yajur Veda** translated by Sri Devi Chand Chapter 40 shloka 9).

This particular shloka is a criticism of materialists and hedonists and not as critics say of idol worship. One should be extremely careful in reading the internet. I would also like to point out that interpreting the Vedas and the Gita in such a manner as to show that they say opposite things can be done only by ignoring centuries old traditional commentaries which have harmonized the Gita and the Vedas. There is no reason to believe these modern interpreters and throw away the centuries old interpretations without some important reason to do so.

The translation given of Gita 7.24 seems to be not correct.

> Without any insight into My transcendental nature, unique and
> immutable, men of little understanding look upon Me as a mere human
> individual, having come into manifestation from an unmanifested state.

**Gita 7.24**

> Ordinary men, especially most of His contemporaries, take the Lord
> Incarnate only as an ordinary man, may be with great powers....  . It
> will be seen that this was true of Rama of whom even many of the Rsis
> of Dandakaranya declared that they knew him to be the 'son of
> Dasaratha' and not as the Divinity Incarnate. Even Krishna was not
> recognised by many of his contemporaries as anything more than a great
> Yadava, though according to the Bhagavata account many great men and
> those who came into intimate contact with him recognised his divinity.
> Hence in the verse under comment, it is said that this is the case
> with the average men who are characterised as ignorant. ... The
> recognition and worship of the Incarnation stands on a different
> footing from that of the deities. The Lord Incarnate is hypostatic
> with the Supreme Being, and His worship is the worship of the Supreme
> Being Himself.

**Commentary of Gita 7.24** by Swami Tapasyananda

The verse actually supports the concept of Avatar.

I am adding this Gita shloka which clearly can not be understood without murthi worship.

> Whoever makes an offering to Me with devotion, be it of leaf,
> flower,fruit or water - that devout offering made by a pure-hearted
> man, I accept with joy.

**Gita 9.26**

Where would you put these offerings if there is no murthi or image?

Comment: I am very sorry for not using mature words. I understand what you are trying to say. But then how are the Vedas and the Bhagavad Gita in some verses saying that idol worship leads to sin be justified? How can one say that idol worship is wrong, and still promote idol worship? If it was like that, then Shri Krishna Ji would have only promoted formful worship and not say that those who have lost their intelligence through worldly means do idol worship. In the same way, the Vedas would have only promoted formless worship and never say that formful worship is wrong.

Comment: It is as if mother and father are opposing each other and the child is confused and lost and does not know what to do.

Comment: @PardeepKumar There is no confusion here-There are two forms of upasanas described in Hindu Scriptures and both are valid.1) **Pratika**  & 2) **Ahangraha**,,In the first one we have some form to meditate upon and there is no such form in the second..the first one is easy the second one is a lot more difficult..& the first form of upasana gradually leads to the second form..

Comment: @PardeepKumar there is nothing against using pratika (you are calling idol worship).Please give exact references where the Vedas or Upanishads say that murthi puja or pratika upasana is wrong. Hindus do not worship idols but worship God through a murthi.

Comment: **Hindus do not worship idols but worship God through a murthi.** Yes,tht's the most common misconception that many people have...

Comment: In what way is this a misconception? Please explain.

Comment: That Hindus worship only idols..actually they don't understand that the idol is not just an object..the **prana** of the deity has already been invoked in it through the mantras prescribed in scriptures..In yajnas we invoke god in fire and they can be invoked in water too(as in tarpanam)..So idol here is not important at all..anyone can invoke any deity in a flower too..

Comment: What you stated is exactly what I meant when I wrote that 'God is worshipped through a murthi'. When the prana is invoked in the murthi then God is worshipped through that murthi. The point I am trying to make is that @PardeepKumar, like Muslims and Christians, is alleging that Hindus worship a lifeless piece of stone (idol in his words) and not God. I am saying that he is wrong and Hindus are worshipping God through the murthi.

Comment: Pradip Gangopadhyay @Rickross The verses that I am referring to are:

1: “They enter darkness those who worship natural things.They sink deeper in  darkness those who worship sambhuti (created things)
(Yajurved 40:9)

2: “Those whose intelligence has been  stolen by material desires they worship demigods i.e. idols."
Bhagavad Gita 7:20)

And also Swami Dayanand Saraswati etc were some famous hindus who condemned idol worship.

Comment: @PardeepKumar In an idol or in fire or in water we first invoke God's presence...thru mantras(most people don't understand this life-giving power of mantras)then its worshiped..so we are neither worshiping natural things nor created things...we are worshiping God only..and u shud also ask  disciples of Dayananda S ,what do they worship when they offer oblations in fire?natural things or created things or something else?..I think u just need a SatGuru that's all.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Thank you very much Pradip Gangopadhyay and Rickross for clearing my misconceptions. Please pray for me that my faith may grow strong and the thought that Hinduism is wrong may never occur in my mind. And please forgive me for whoever I offended. I should not have used such immature words.

Answer (score 1):

“They enter darkness those who worship natural things.They sink deeper in darkness those who worship sambhuti (created things)" (Yajurved 40:9)

"God Supreme or Supreme Spirit has no ‘Pratima’ (idol) or material shape" (Yajurved chapter 32 verse 3)

“Those whose intelligence has been stolen by material desires they worship demigods i.e. idols." (Bhagavad Gita 7:20)     ***He became formless himself, They became formless... The Idol worship is to create the awareness of his life in means of science and that doesn't mean that God will look alike the Idol.. The one who admires God will love to be the way he was... And the "way" will lead to dharma and outer bliss ....***

"The ignorant believe that un-manifest Para Brahma (One God) incarnates or takes manifestations, because they do not completely understand My highest, immutable, incomparable, and transcendental existence." (Bhagavad Gita 7:24)    ***True they are formless, Only through determined love and devotion, he becomes a form.  Incarnation must have a reason***

Answer (score 0):

I can only say, those are not contradictory at all. you just have to understand some simple concepts. It is easy to get confused as the underlying knowledge is not clearly written and were expected to be taught by the guru only because written knowledge can be misinterpreted unless there is any interactive session. Well, as far as I realized,
1. God is eternal and formless. As God is formless, He can not have a physical boundary because if he has a boundary, the boundary will define His form. Therefore, He is omnipresent. If He is omnipresent, He lives inside every objects in this universe and beyond (including the idols and pictures). So, there is nothing wrong to assume a stone (or any other object) as the God and worship it. Now the question comes if I worship a random object as God, does it actually connect us with God? Isn't it like sitting inside a pool and thinking of water? then what is the nessecity of idols or temples? the answer is it is not important what form you are thinking about, the important thing is you are thinking about Him. Now if I ask you to think about a formless, propertyless object (even object word is not applicable) you will find it difficult to imagine. So we have to imagine a form. ok, so which form you should imagine? it is easiest to imagine something or someone you can respect. What or whom do you respect most? People you want to be like or objects you desire most. Mother (God), Father (God), teacher (God), Money (God, Laxmi), The wealthiest entity (God, Laxmi), Knowledge and most knowledgeable entity (Saraswati), Most powerful (Shakti). This way every entity you think to be God is connected to your desire. Sounds negative? Not at all. This is the way you and your desires get connected to the God. This is the preliminary step. without it you will think your desires and emotions as something disconnected from God. You may even start thinking them as evil (like buddhism, I am not criticising buddhism, its just another approach). Well, talking about avatars, I think avatars are not born, they are forged. It is a position to gain. People who are the most adept in specific field are the avatars. How do we know? Because one of the avatars was adept in self-realization. Lord Krishna. Read Bibhutiyoga chapter in Bhagbat Gita. Now lets connect the missing link. Moksha. It is not about seeing or meeting God. Its about becoming God. If you can become YOUR God, you got moksha. Say you are a scholar and you imagine God to be a person with infinite knowledge. You may become your God if you gain infinite knowledge. Ya, its impossible (apperently). But if you go enough beyond the imagination of people, to world you are already God. We know lord Rama to be the God. Albert Einstein is an avatar of Saraswati (atleast to me. who knows if Balmiki was present in modern world, he could recognize him). Now if you are too orthodox to accept possibility of this concept, I will request you to re-read the scriptures once with keeping this in your mind.

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE ! With fully appreciating your views regarding the subject ,I would like to  request you to add some sources  from authentic Hindu Scriptures in your answer.Citing sources is a must on this site ,otherwise your answer will be just like a personal comment and might get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I am bewildered why this question has been downvoted. So i took the liberty of upvoting. It's an important consideration that could easily be lost in translation. Now i need to say straight up that i am not Hindu, nor Indian, nor do i speak Sanskrit. Although I wish I was all of these things. I would like to say that, I've been studying ancient texts - especially in relation to polytheistic religions for 15 years as a hobby. I think the part of the Vedas that you are referring to, ultimately is epitomized by the saying:

> "He who worships ignorance, enters blind darkness. He who worships
>   knowledge, enters blind darkness, as it were yet deeper. It is
>   different they say for knowledge; it is different they say for
>   ignorance. Or so we have heard from the wise before us. For by
>   ignorance one crosses mortality, and by knowledge one crosses
>   immortality"

This is taken i believe from the Upanisads. I believe you're reading from: VÂGASANEYI-SAMHITÂ-UPANISHAD. A long translation of which, can be found here:

[VÂGASANEYI-SAMHITÂ-UPANISHAD](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe01/sbe01243.htm)

However translations like this can end up too verbose for their own good. Something more succinct I actually found more meaningful; like the penguin translation of this chapter summarised by the quote above.

I recommend the penguin translation for the Bhagavad Gita, the Upanisads and the Rig Veda. If you are missioning it through the vedas (as i did - good on you!) I recommend Ralph Griffith - not because he's a good translator, more because he dedicated his entire life to try and translate the vedas, and that must count for something - and there are few alternatives. Ralph's translation of the Sama Veda is actually very good - especially initially. The translation starts like the beginning of Shakespeare's Macbeth; which is particularly befitting of white / light-grey witchcraft of this calibre.

In relation to your references of symbolism. I'd say that Hindus, prefer to represent the philosophical concepts of Jains through symbolic representation. This may manifest itself as idols, however the idiology is only a method of abstraction to assist in remembering the hundreds of thousands of pages of text in the Vedas. This is much like almost all other religions have done, and in my view does not constitute idol worship - since it is just a psychological mechanism of helping to remember one of myriad concepts that are presented in the Vedas and the Upanisads.

As an aside, my interpretation of Hinduism, is that it's a colourful devolution of Jainism. I mean no offense by this, on the contrary; i prefer Hindu methods of expression, since I believe I can remember them more clearly under Hinduism than Jainism. Now, I would say at this point that I believe Hinduism, like Jainism is a Pantheist religion; not Panantheist. That is to say that God and reality are synonymous. Or, to quote a Jain tenant:

> The absolute is impersonal.

In relation to your quotation:

> śailī dāru-mayī lauhī lepyā lekhyā ca saikatī mano-mayī maṇi-mayī pratimāṣṭa-vidhā smṛtā [SB - 11.27.12]

I believe this means that God (the one God, as mentioned in the Bhagavad Gita as being the "Poet" / "Creator") has various manifestations in nature. The way I think about this is in relation to the God "Shiva". If you see a picture of Shiva, Shiva has many arms each holding a celestrial weapon, each weapon represents a force of nature that can destroy. In my view - not just in Hinduism, but also in religions like egyptology different Gods represent different aspects or forces of nature, in the same way that Shiva has many arms.

Also I'd like to take the opportunity at this point to express my interpretation of "creator" in the context of religions, such as Hinduism. Thanks to religions such as Christianity, we have come to accept creation as a Biblical Genesis creation of heaven and earth. Yet, when you compare this to the creation versus of the Rig Vedas, you seen interesting comparisons, and a new perspective on Genesis. See it could be that in Genesis when it says:

> Genesis 1New International Version (NIV) The Beginning
>
> 1 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth. 2 Now the
>   earth was formless and empty, darkness was over the surface of the
>   deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters.
>
> 3 And God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light. 4 God saw
>   that the light was good, and he separated the light from the darkness.
>   5 God called the light “day,” and the darkness he called “night.” And
>   there was evening, and there was morning—the first day.
>
> 6 And God said, “Let there be a vault between the waters to separate
>   water from water.” 7 So God made the vault and separated the water
>   under the vault from the water above it. And it was so. 8 God called
>   the vault “sky.” And there was evening, and there was morning—the
>   second day.
>
> 9 And God said, “Let the water under the sky be gathered to one place,
>   and let dry ground appear.” And it was so. 10 God called the dry
>   ground “land,” and the gathered waters he called “seas.” And God saw
>   that it was good.
>
> 11 Then God said, “Let the land produce vegetation: seed-bearing
>   plants and trees on the land that bear fruit with seed in it,
>   according to their various kinds.” And it was so. 12 The land produced
>   vegetation: plants bearing seed according to their kinds and trees
>   bearing fruit with seed in it according to their kinds. And God saw
>   that it was good. 13 And there was evening, and there was morning—the
>   third day.

You see, my interpretation of this would be from a Solipsistic perspective. In my view this wasn't the creation of Heaven and Earth, this was the creation of consciousness of an individual. The waters were the womb, the light was the birth of a baby, the creation of various things were the eyesight of the baby extending in focal length. If you compare this interpretation to the creation versus of the Rig Veda it talks of the pillars of the Mind that support the sky and the universe, in so much as consciousness is necessary to appreciate the concept of existance, and without this concept, existance really has no meaning. Or:

> Cognito ergo sum

Quite literally:

> I think, therefore [consequently] I am.

My interpretation of Descartes meaning is not so much a logical conclusion; instead i see the meaning that his [meaningful] existence is a consequence of of his thoughts. That his consciousness, in a sense brought his existence into being. And that without interpretation existence is void of meaning or presence.

Indeed Arthur Schopenhauer would take it one step further and tie meaning into something more, such as:

> Life without pain has no meaning.

However in the case of Hinduism, I think that the Poet is not the creator anything specific, but the creator of each and every moment in the now. Quite literally "it" is the creation of time in perpetuity. The movement of one instance of time to the next. This is crucial, there cannot be existence without time; in fact the explanation of all things, is time. This is why i believe in the Bhagavad Gita, in chapter 7 it refers to precisely one God, and all other Gods being a conduit to that one God. The poet, i believe is quite literally the God of Time and all metaphysical constructs are a derivation from this one concept.

Anyway, I am digressing...

Re the contradiction. It is my belief that the Bhagavad Gita states that God is the superlative in all aspects of existence, and exists as idealistic construct that humanity aspires to, yet never can obtain. Although a Jain tenant is that:

> Through supreme effort one can become Godly.

Therefore I see no contradiction whatsoever between BG and SBP. Since this can never be idolized, and idol worship in my view is the hollow dogmatic doctrine of following a principle-less existence devoid of meaning and content - see Aristotle's philosophy about how the principles of something comes to be define the entity.

Answer (score 0):

No:  scriptures just inform that God is formless with respect to us(since it's our drawback actually), they never specifically tell to stop worshipping idols (but should be always exactly performed with right arrangements, most importantly should be with right faith in the ❤️ heart.)

Yes, that's true that God theoretically doesn't have any specifically one shape/form.

What's capability of human eye is colors in the range of VIBGYOR.

Still usually, humans like to believe only in what they see, if there wouldn't have been electron microscopes humans couldn't have believed in the existence of the covid-19 viruses and would have thought about some illusionary possible cause which affected humans worldwide.

Similarly, as we don't have any instruments yet to measure/view the oppulences of God. So, we must follow up with the Divine Doctorate Healers who through innumerable births doing God- pleasing deeds achieved mercy to receive that DIVINE EXPERIENCE-

> **न तु मां शक्यसे द्रष्टुमनेनैव स्वचक्षुषा |
> दिव्यं ददामि ते चक्षु: पश्य मे योगमैश्वरम् || 8||**
> Translation
> **BG 11.8: But you cannot see my cosmic form with these physical eyes of yours. Therefore, I grant you divine vision. Behold my majestic opulence!**

So, considering the incapability of the humans- God described himself in depth of his various most important opulences in brief, whom we all manushya devoutly worship without second thought as a service to universal supreme God himself: "Chapter 10: The Opulence of the Absolute"-

> Arjuna enquires God:
> Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 10, Verse 16-17
> वक्तुमर्हस्यशेषेण दिव्या ह्यात्मविभूतय: |
> याभिर्विभूतिभिर्लोकानिमांस्त्वं व्याप्य तिष्ठसि || 16||
> कथं विद्यामहं योगिंस्त्वां सदा परिचिन्तयन् |
> केषु केषु च भावेषु चिन्त्योऽसि भगवन्मया || 17||
> Translation
> BG 10.16-17: **Please describe to me your divine opulences, by which you pervade all the worlds and reside in them. O Supreme Master of Yog, how may I know you and think of you. And while meditating, in what forms can I think of you, O Supreme Divine Personality?**

God gave knowledge about his most important opulences:

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/10

The above chapter has 42 slokas as said by the YOGESHWAR LORD about his opulences.

Note: In the last sloka of Chapter 10, God after providing eternal knowledge about his divine opulences says-
although have described the important aspects, manifestations, still no one can know completely all different opulences-

> Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 10, Verse 42
> अथवा बहुनैतेन किं ज्ञातेन तवार्जुन |
> विष्टभ्याहमिदं कृत्स्नमेकांशेन स्थितो जगत् || 42||
> **atha vā bahunaitena kiṁ jñātena tavārjuna
> viṣhṭabhyāham idaṁ kṛitsnam ekānśhena sthito jagat**
> Translation
> **BG 10.42: What need is there for all this detailed knowledge, O Arjun? Simply know that by one fraction of my being, I pervade and support this entire creation.**

---

In the chapter 11,

Since, Arjuna didn't have divine eyes, God bestowed the same-

> Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 11, Verse 47
> **श्रीभगवानुवाच |
> मया प्रसन्नेन तवार्जुनेदं
> रूपं परं दर्शितमात्मयोगात् |
> तेजोमयं विश्वमनन्तमाद्यं
> यन्मे त्वदन्येन न दृष्टपूर्वम् || 47||**
> Translation
> BG 11.47: YOGESHWAR Lord said: **Arjun, being pleased with you, by my Yogmaya power, I gave you a vision of my resplendent, unlimited, and primeval cosmic form. No one before you has ever seen it.**
> Because of the divine vision thus provided by God, Arjuna reveals about the eternal VISHWAROOPAM form as follows-
> Bhagavad Gita 11.16 »
> **I see your infinite form in every direction, with countless arms, stomachs, faces, and eyes. O Lord of the universe, whose form is the universe itself, I do not see in you any beginning, middle, or end.**
> Bhagavad Gita 11.17»
> **I see your form, adorned with a crown, and armed with the club and disc, shining everywhere as the abode of splendor. It is hard to look upon you in the blazing fire of your effulgence, which is radiating like the sun in all directions.**
> Bhagavad Gita 11.18 »
> **I recognize you as the supreme imperishable being, the ultimate truth to be known by the scriptures. You are the support of all creation; you are the eternal protector of sanātan dharma (the eternal religion); and you are the everlasting Supreme Divine Personality.**
> Bhagavad Gita 11.19 »
> **You are without beginning, middle, or end; your power has no limits. Your arms are infinite; the sun and the moon are like your eyes, and fire is like your mouth. I see you warming the entire creation by your radiance.**
> Bhagavad Gita 11.20-
> **The space between heaven and earth and all the directions are pervaded by you alone. Seeing your wondrous and terrible form, I see the three worlds trembling in fear, O Greatest of all beings.**

God said the VISHWAROOPAM isn't viewable as such to any.

> Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 11, Verse 52-53
> **श्रीभगवानुवाच |
> सुदुर्दर्शमिदं रूपं दृष्टवानसि यन्मम |
> देवा अप्यस्य रूपस्य नित्यं दर्शनकाङ्क्षिण: || 52||
> नाहं वेदैर्न तपसा न दानेन न चेज्यया |
> शक्य एवंविधो द्रष्टुं दृष्टवानसि मां यथा || 53||**
> Translation
> **BG 11.52-53: The Supreme Lord said: This form of mine that you are seeing is exceedingly difficult to behold. Even the celestial gods are eager to see it. Neither by the study of the Vedas, nor by penance, charity, or fire sacrifices, can I be seen as you have seen me.**

Conclusion:
Athough God has above VISHWAROOPAM form, which can't be seen with biological eyes, thus- God is generally said to be formless, imperceivable:

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 11, Verse 48-

> **न वेदयज्ञाध्ययनैर्न दानै-
> र्न च क्रियाभिर्न तपोभिरुग्रै: |
> एवंरूप: शक्य अहं नृलोके
> द्रष्टुं त्वदन्येन कुरुप्रवीर || 48||**
> Translation
> **BG 11.48: Not by study of the Vedas, nor by the performance of sacrifice, rituals, or charity, nor even by practicing severe austerities, has any mortal ever seen what you have seen, O best of the Kuru warriors.**

***Thus, as God already clarified most difficult doubts- so, humans can without discriminations, conflict of thoughts wisely progress along the spiritual path righteously like Arjuna.***

Similarly, we see various VISHWAROOPAM across scriptures like

> 1)Sri Hanumanji burning off the Lanka:
> दोहा :
> Doha:

- हरि प्रेरित तेहि अवसर चले मरुत उनचास।
  अट्टहास करि गर्जा कपि बढ़ि लाग अकास॥25॥
  भावार्थ:-उस समय भगवान् की प्रेरणा से उनचासों पवन चलने लगे। हनुमान्जी अट्टहास करके गर्जे और बढ़कर आकाश से जा लगे॥25॥
  English: At that moment, impelled by God, all the forty-nine winds began to bluster. Hanuman roared with a loud laugh and swelled to such a size that he seemed to touch the sky.
  (The Forty nine winds bluster wildly only during Pralaya as such)

---

> 2. Narsimhadev's terrible form is well Known when he kills the unkillable Hiranyakashipu, at the end Shiva's Sharabeshwar swaroop had to pacify the viraat form of Narsimhasdevji.
>    3) Goddess Kalika kills Raktabija asur, encircling the earth with her  tongue drinking off his blood, whole earth flows full of blood that time Shiva Mahakaal pacifies her at end as universal dissolution was near due to the angered Kaalika.
>    4)God Veerbhadra in his Vishwaroopam, destroyed Daksha yagna, disturbed, feared off whosoever attended it, brought Daksha's arrogant head to Lord Shiva
>    5)Lord Shiva comes to marry Goddess Uma in death like old aged form, along with innumerable  ghosts.
>    6)Lord Shiva appears in his unconquerable ENLIGHTENED ENERGY PILLAR CALLED JYOTIRLINGAM VISHWAROOPAM in midst of the Hari, Brahmaji chaos over supremacy, when both asked who are you - ***he said **I am God, I am Shiva**.***

Form worship is utmost importance as per our scriptures.

Comment: Again, you need to use blockquotes when quoting someone/something. Check [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/41212/revisions) edit on how to use them.