# Are there any signs (or lakshnas) that determine the ItihAsha scriptures?

Tags: scripture, itihasa

We know that the PurAnas have 5 signs or `lakshnas`. If a scripture does not have those 5 signs then it can not be called a PurAna.

These 5 signs are shared by all PurAnas i.e by the 18 major (mahA) and the 18 minor (upa) ones.

For the major PurAnas, however, there are additional 5 signs, so in all 10 signs are there for any major PurAna.

Likewise, the Tantras also have several lakshanas. The YAmala Tantras too has separate such lakshanas of their own.

**I want to know, whether the ItihAshas too have some signs? If yes, what are those and in which scriptures are they mentioned?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are only Ramayana and Mahabharata classified as Itihasa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11813/why-are-only-ramayana-and-mahabharata-classified-as-itihasa)