# Which are the characteristics of brAhmaNas?

Tags: brahmanas

We know that there are five to ten characteristics (Lakshana) of Purana which are discussed in [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16752/277). A [similar question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20762/277) also asked for Itihasa. I want to know are there any characteristics of [Brahmanas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmana) mentioned in scripture or in works of Acharyas?

Comment: What is the purpose of using consistent transliteration? That too only for single letter in the title only and not anywhere else?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma when one reads only title of question from the list of questions, there is possibility of reading [Brahman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahman) rather than [BrAhmana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmana).

Comment: You very well know title is not the complete question. We should do standardization everywhere. There is only one Brahman. Not multiple. We have tags to denote that it is Brahmanas and not Brahman. Brahmana is not same as Brahman. Even if it is not clear, then use proper transliteration according to some scheme. write brAhmaNa is ITRANS. not BrAhmana

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Yes, corrected as per ITRANS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Brahmans are the very important text and part of Vedas, which contains instructions and explanation to the sacrifices and rituals and procedures for performing them. There are **ten characteristics** of Brahmanas described by [Shabara Swami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Aabara) in his Bhashya on [(Purva) Mimansa Sutras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purva_Mimamsa_Sutras) of Jaimini.

[**Shabara Bhashya**](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%BD%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A5%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%83_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%83) on Purva Mimansa Sutra 2.1.33:

> हेतुर्निर्वचनं निन्दा प्रशंसा संशयो विधिः।
>   परक्रिया पुराकल्पो व्यवधारणकल्पना ।।
>   उपमानं दशैते तु विधयो ब्राह्मणस्य तु। 
>   एतद्वै सर्ववेदेषु नियतं विधिलक्षणम् ।।
>
> Heturnirvacanaṃ Nindā Praśaṃsā Saṃśayo Vidhiḥ।
>   Parakriyā Purākalpo Vyavadhāraṇakalpanā ।।
>   Upamānaṃ Daśaite tu Vidhayo Brāhmaṇasya tu। 
>   etadvai sarvavedeṣu niyataṃ vidhilakṣaṇam ।।

They are as follows:

1. **Hetu** i.e **statement of reason** is the description of the cause for the sacrifice.
2. **Nirvachana** i.e **interpretation** or etymology is the derivational interpretation of the words
3. **Nindā** i.e **depreciation** is the the discouragement of the forbidden acts.
4. **Praśaṃsā** i.e **eulogation** is the encouragement of the good acts.
5. **Saṃśaya** i.e **doubt**  is the clarification of doubts.
6. **Vidhi** i.e **injunction** is the direction and order of rites in sacrifices.
7. **Parakriyā** i.e **act of others** is the description of goodness of the sub-ordinate rites in main sacrifice.
8. **Purākalpa** i.e **ancient history** is the description of historical incidents and stories.
9. **Vyavadhāraṇakalpanā** i.e **assumption of transposition** is the arrangement of the instruments and objects in the sacrifice according to the ircumstances.
10. **Upamānaṃ** i.e **analogy** is the example.

---

Source/Reference:

- [Chapter I Vedic Literature](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/138507/8/08_chapter%20i.pdf) page 23,24 (30,31)
- [Shabara Bhasya Translated By Ganganath Jha](https://archive.org/details/ShabaraBhasyaTrByGanganathJha) page 204 (218) [*recommended to refer that page*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEeda.jpg)