# In which Kalpa did Markendya's story take place?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, yama, markandeya

We had read about the sage Markendaya story where Lord Shiva saves the 16-year old boy from Yama and blessed him with immortality. Do we have any reference to which Kalpa, Mahayuga, Manvantra it happened? The Markendaya through intense devotion won over death due to grace of Shiva.

Comment: I went to the temple - Amirthakadeshwarar temple in Tamil Nadu and that temple history was the Markandeya story. It seemed to have happened there

Comment: Can anyone show reference to this question

Comment: Different Puranas describe events from different Kalpas as this answer says https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11077/8735. One version of Markendya story is mentioned in Skanda puran so you could say it happened in Satpurusha kalpa

Comment: @Ketan when was Satpurusha Kalpa? Prior to Padma kalpa? 49th year of brahma?

Comment: Order of Kalpas is something that I have been trying to figure out too. Sorry I don’t know yet :-)