# What is Gaṇeśa's birth name?

Tags: ganesha, name

Gaṇeśa or gaṇapati means "lord or leader of the gaṇas" where gaṇa means "flock, troop, multitude, tribe." This means that Gaṇeśa is a title and not his name. When Parvati create him, wasn't he given a proper name before he became the leader of the Gaṇas—perhaps when he had his original head?

Comment: According to Padma Purana, his name was Gangeya because he was son of Ganga (water) i.e., born of water. He was created with an elephant head. No incident of beheading happens according to that purana.

Comment: Nice Q...May be Shambara or Shambh...

Comment: I see. So there is no agreement on his creation? I only knew of the story from when Parvati made him from sandalwood.

Comment: Related of duplicate of [What was the name of Ganesha before beheading done by Lord Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3888/3500)

Comment: Oh maaan. I swear I searched before asking. I think the SE search is broken. this has happened to me a few times. Thanks.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī Ok. If you are ok with it, i will close.

Comment: I suppose you have to close it, but the person who asked the other question picked the wrong answer. It said he was not called anything, yet you clearly show he was called "son."